# How to get single column table values from mysql db to dropdownbox using php ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How to get single column table values from mysql db to dropdownbox using php ajax?

For eg:
i have some name list in my dropdownbox when i select particular name from that, then the details(say gender or age) of particular name (will be get from mysql db) will be display in another textbox/dropdownbox without reloading the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Ajax will solve your requirement

Comment: Provide some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Im trying for getting all the values of an entry on the day to a dropdownbox only when i select particular date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery, for example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

$("#dropdownlist1").change(function()
{

var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_dropdownlist2_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#dropdownlist2").html(html);
        }
    }); 

});
```

});

HTML

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM rx_type";           
$res_type=mysql_query($sql);            
?>  
<select name="dropdownlist1" id="dropdownlist1" >
    <option value=""> -- Type -- </option>            
    <?php            
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_type)){            
    ?>            
    <option value="<?=$row1['type_id']?>"><?=$row1['type_name']?></option>            
    <?php   }   ?> 
</select>

<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM rx_size ORDER BY drug_size";           
$res_size=mysql_query($sql);            
?>  
<select name="dropdownlist2" id="dropdownlist2" >
    <option value=""> -- Size -- </option>            
    <?php            
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_size)){            
    ?>            
    <option value="<?=$row1['drug_size_id']?>"><?=$row1['drug_size']?></option>            
    <?php   }   ?> 
</select>
```

load_dropdownlist2_data.php

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from your table WHERE .drug_id = $id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $id3=$row['drug_size_id'];
    $data=$row['drug_size'];
    echo '<option value="'.$id3.'">'.$data.'</option>';
    }       
?>
```

Comment: thanks for info.. i ll chk it now.. and will ask if i get any doubts

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX query for that. Bind event "onchange" with given select box that triggers ajax query which gets values from db and returns them as json array. Next append it to the container. Of course you'll need some escaping via PHP to prevent injections but the general look should be this:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['getGenders'])) {

  $name = $_POST['name']; // get the name from the post

  // db validation & query, save it to result array (that contains keys like age=>12, gender=>female ($result variable)
  ...


  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($result);

}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="names">
  <option value="john">John</option>
  <option value="john">James</option>
</select>

<div id="result">
  <span id="gender"></span>
  <span id="age"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript (requires Jquery):

```
$("#names").on("change", function(){

    var name = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

        url: "/data.php",
        data: "name="+name,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(resp) {

            $('#gender').html(resp.gender);
            $('#age').html(resp.age);

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: but i need to get the values from database.. how can i do diz??